# How to write the CharAt method in Java

Tags: java

I am supposed to write out the charAt method in java, without using charAt.  I have no idea where to start.

The only method I am aloud to call in my charAt method is .length().

I am not trying to call the charAt method, I am trying to write the charAt method.

Comment: A string is basically a list of characters. `charAt()` returns the character at a given index. Is it really so hard to connect the dots yourself?

Comment: Just for info, why do you want to reinvent wheel by writing your own charAt?

Comment: Cause its an assignment that I can't start.

Comment: Start by thinking about what `charAt()` does. The method you write will have to search a string to find the character at the specified index. One implementation would be to loop through the array of characters and count the iterations until you come to the index passed to the method. Then you return the character found at that position.

Comment: Is the intent of this assignment to simulate the actual instance method inside of the String class, or to write is as a utility method that takes a String as a parameter?

Comment: Yes. It takes a string parameter

Answer (score 1):

That's a weird assignment... I would convert the string to a charArray so you can easily access characters via index:

```
 public char charAt(String str, int index){
     char[] array = str.toCharArray()
     return array[index]
 }
```

Or you could use String.split() and loop over the array generated:

```
public String charAt(String str, int index){
     String strArray[] = str.split(""); //generates array of strings, each with only one character
     return strArray[index]
}
```

Using str.length, you could loop over the string and return a substring. However, the return value would have to be a String, not a char:

```
public String charAt(String str, int index){
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
        if(i == index)
            return str.substring(i, i+1)
    }
    return ""
}
```

Comment: I am not allowed to use .toCharArray() unfortunately.

Comment: No... it won't disregard that. You can't convert from a String to a char

Comment: We are only allowed length() by my interpretation of the assignment.

Comment: Still only allowed length.  No substring.

Comment: There's simply no way to access separate components of a string without using methods of the String class. The only other way that I haven't mentioned to get separate characters would be to use the String.copyValueOf() method, which generates a char array. Look over the assignment again, that can't be what it's asking.

Comment: You can only use the String methods charAt and length, in addition to String concatenation with the '+' operator. You cannot use any other String or Character methods in your class!

All of the methods below operate on the instance variable of type String stored in the Pseudo class:

Declare a public method called charAt that takes an index parameter and returns the character in the stored string at the index. You can assume that the index is valid, i.e. between 0 and String.length()-1

Comment: That sounds like you're allowed to use `charAt`?  But if you can't use anything except `length` then it's downright impossible, full stop.

Comment: If you can use `charAt`, then just loop through the array using `length` and return the index of the loop when it equals the index passed through the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *substring(start_index, end_index)* method with end index 1 greater than start index.

```
String str = new String("Alternatives");
System.out.println("Start position=4 and end position=5: "
            + str.substring(4,5));
```

Output:
  Start position=4 and end position=5: r

It works as charAt(4).